# Aurelia failed binding not throwing error?

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I was wondering if aurelia should throw error on failed binding ? I use durandal a lot, and a useful feature was "binder.throwOnErrors = true;" If a binding failed it would throw an error in the console.

But in aurelia, say i got a "version" var in my VM. If i bind

```html
${non-existing-var}
```

or even

```html
${non-existing-object.non-existing-property}
```

it won't say anything.

So far aurelia is good, but sometimes it's a real pain to dig the template and to figure why the binding ain't working.

I've tried to dig in the aurelia-binding class, but could not find any clue.
Thank you :)

I also use the default configuration (i see [Debug] logs in the console)

```js
aurelia.use
  .standardConfiguration()
  .developmentLogging();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aurelia does not throw when an attempt is made to bind to an null/undefined property (or chain of properties). This is intentional- Aurelia supports binding to things that aren't yet defined but will become defined later.

Other developers have requested an option log these occurrences be added. This request is tracked [here](https://github.com/aurelia/binding/issues/30).

Comment: Well, reading that it really make sense, should have figured myself. Not having to use knockout observable, it make sense aurelia should support undefined/null vars. It cannot bind to an intermediate object. Thank you